High Deployment Cost Issue on Sepolia Testnet
The problem is as follows: when I try to deploy, the cost is too high, and I don't understand why, even though I have 0.8 ETH on Sepolia. The command I use is npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/NFTModule.ts --network sepolia (I also tried with scripts/deploy.ts, but it didn't work). Locally with Hardhat, everything works fine, but when I try to switch to a testnet, it doesn't work. I'm using Infura as the endpoint, and it shows me 30 requests made by me (like for eth_getTransactionCount, eth_estimateGas, eth_getBlockByNumber, etc.). Can someone help me understand the problem?

Currently, there’s some issue with Ethereum Sepolia testnet. The gas fees are spiked.

Yeah the gas price is 166 gwei
